# Problem with installing Qiskit on Android with Termux emulator

Tags: qiskit, programming

Termux has some issues with `cmake`, therefore qiskit-aer-0.5.2 installation returns error 1.

```
Collecting qiskit
  Downloading qiskit-0.19.6.tar.gz (4.0 kB)
Collecting qiskit-terra==0.14.2
  Downloading qiskit-terra-0.14.2.tar.gz (6.3 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 6.3 MB 110 kB/s
Collecting qiskit-aer==0.5.2
  Downloading qiskit-aer-0.5.2.tar.gz (10.3 MB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 10.3 MB 60 kB/s
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/python3 -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-891uqs3t/qiskit-aer/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-891uqs3t/qiskit-aer/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-pip-egg-info-v59grdvz
         cwd: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-891uqs3t/qiskit-aer/
    Complete output (559 lines):
      ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
       command: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/python3 -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-wheel-3e9istkf/cmake/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-wheel-3e9istkf/cmake/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' bdist_wheel -d /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-wheel-76sn2q3h
           cwd: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-wheel-3e9istkf/cmake/
      Complete output (520 lines):


      --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      -- Trying "Ninja" generator
      --------------------------------
      ---------------------------
      ----------------------
      -----------------
      ------------
      -------
      --
      Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
      CMake Error: CMake was unable to find a build program corresponding to "Ninja".  CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM is not set.  You probably need to select a different build tool.
      -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
      See also "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-wheel-3e9istkf/cmake/_cmake_test_compile/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
      --
      -------
      ------------
      -----------------
      ----------------------
      ---------------------------
      --------------------------------
      -- Trying "Ninja" generator - failure
      --------------------------------------------------------------------------------



      --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      -- Trying "Unix Makefiles" generator
      --------------------------------
      ---------------------------
      ----------------------
      -----------------
      ------------
      -------
      --
      Not searching for unused variables given on the command line.
      -- The C compiler identification is Clang 10.0.1
      -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
      -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
      -- Check for working C compiler: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/cc - skipped
      -- Detecting C compile features
      -- Detecting C compile features - done
      -- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 10.0.1
      -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
      -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
      -- Check for working CXX compiler: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/c++ - skipped
      -- Detecting CXX compile features
      -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
      -- Configuring done
      -- Generating done
      -- Build files have been written to: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-wheel-3e9istkf/cmake/_cmake_test_compile/build
      --
      -------
      ------------
      -----------------
      ----------------------
      ---------------------------
      --------------------------------
      -- Trying "Unix Makefiles" generator - success
      --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

      Configuring Project
        Working directory:
          /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-wheel-3e9istkf/cmake/_skbuild/linux-armv8l-3.8/cmake-build
        Command:
          cmake /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-wheel-3e9istkf/cmake -G 'Unix Makefiles' -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-wheel-3e9istkf/cmake/_skbuild/linux-armv8l-3.8/cmake-install/cmake/data -DPYTHON_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/python3 -DPYTHON_VERSION_STRING:STRING=3.8.5 -DPYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/include/python3.8 -DPYTHON_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/libpython3.8.so -DSKBUILD:BOOL=TRUE -DCMAKE_MODULE_PATH:PATH=/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/skbuild/resources/cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release

      -- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 10.0.1
      -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
      -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
      -- Check for working CXX compiler: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/c++ - skipped
      -- Detecting CXX compile features
      -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
      -- ***************************************************
      -- Build CMake from source: ON
      -- ***************************************************
      -- SuperBuild - CMakeProject-src-download
      -- SuperBuild - CMakeProject-src-download - URL: https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/releases/download/v3.18.0/cmake-3.18.0.tar.gz
      -- SuperBuild - CMakeProject-src-download - CMakeProject_SOURCE_DIR: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-wheel-3e9istkf/cmake/src
      -- SuperBuild -   CMakeProject-build
      -- SuperBuild -   CMakeProject-build - CMakeProject_BINARY_DIR: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-wheel-3e9istkf/cmake/_skbuild/linux-armv8l-3.8/cmake-build/CMakeProject-build
      -- SuperBuild -   CMakePythonDistributions
      -- Configuring done
      -- Generating done
      CMake Warning:
        Manually-specified variables were not used by the project:

          PYTHON_EXECUTABLE
          PYTHON_INCLUDE_DIR
          PYTHON_LIBRARY
          PYTHON_VERSION_STRING
          SKBUILD


      -- Build files have been written to: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-wheel-3e9istkf/cmake/_skbuild/linux-armv8l-3.8/cmake-build
      Scanning dependencies of target CMakeProject-src-download
      [  3%] Creating directories for 'CMakeProject-src-download'
      [  6%] Performing download step (download, verify and extract) for 'CMakeProject-src-download'
      -- Downloading...
         dst='/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-wheel-3e9istkf/cmake/_skbuild/linux-armv8l-3.8/cmake-build/cmake-3.18.0.tar.gz'
         timeout='none'
      -- Using src='https://github.com/Kitware/CMake/releases/download/v3.18.0/cmake-3.18.0.tar.gz'
      -- [download 0% complete]
      -- [download 100% complete]
      -- [download 0% complete]
      -- [download 1% complete]
...
      -- [download 100% complete]
      -- verifying file...
             file='/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-wheel-3e9istkf/cmake/_skbuild/linux-armv8l-3.8/cmake-build/cmake-3.18.0.tar.gz'
      -- Downloading... done
      -- extracting...
           src='/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-wheel-3e9istkf/cmake/_skbuild/linux-armv8l-3.8/cmake-build/cmake-3.18.0.tar.gz'
           dst='/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-wheel-3e9istkf/cmake/src'
      -- extracting... [tar xfz]
      -- extracting... [analysis]
      -- extracting... [rename]
      -- extracting... [clean up]
      -- extracting... done
      [  9%] No update step for 'CMakeProject-src-download'
      [ 12%] No patch step for 'CMakeProject-src-download'
      [ 15%] No configure step for 'CMakeProject-src-download'
      [ 18%] No build step for 'CMakeProject-src-download'
      [ 21%] No install step for 'CMakeProject-src-download'
      [ 24%] Completed 'CMakeProject-src-download'
      [ 24%] Built target CMakeProject-src-download
      Scanning dependencies of target LibUV
      [ 27%] Creating directories for 'LibUV'
      [ 30%] Performing download step (download, verify and extract) for 'LibUV'
      -- Downloading...
         dst='/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-wheel-3e9istkf/cmake/_skbuild/linux-armv8l-3.8/cmake-build/LibUV-prefix/src/libuv-v1.23.0.tar.gz'
         timeout='none'
      -- Using src='https://dist.libuv.org/dist/v1.23.0/libuv-v1.23.0.tar.gz'
      -- [download 0% complete]
      -- [download 1% complete]
....
      -- [download 98% complete]
      -- [download 100% complete]
      -- verifying file...
             file='/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-wheel-3e9istkf/cmake/_skbuild/linux-armv8l-3.8/cmake-build/LibUV-prefix/src/libuv-v1.23.0.tar.gz'
      -- Downloading... done
      -- extracting...
           src='/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-wheel-3e9istkf/cmake/_skbuild/linux-armv8l-3.8/cmake-build/LibUV-prefix/src/libuv-v1.23.0.tar.gz'
           dst='/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-wheel-3e9istkf/cmake/_skbuild/linux-armv8l-3.8/cmake-build/LibUV-src'
      -- extracting... [tar xfz]
      -- extracting... [analysis]
      -- extracting... [rename]
      -- extracting... [clean up]
      -- extracting... done
      [ 33%] No update step for 'LibUV'
      [ 36%] No patch step for 'LibUV'
      [ 39%] Performing configure step for 'LibUV'
      loading initial cache file /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-wheel-3e9istkf/cmake/_skbuild/linux-armv8l-3.8/cmake-build/initial-cache.txt
      loading initial cache file /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-wheel-3e9istkf/cmake/_skbuild/linux-armv8l-3.8/cmake-build/LibUV-prefix/tmp/LibUV-cache-Release.cmake
      -- The C compiler identification is Clang 10.0.1
      -- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 10.0.1
      -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
      -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
      -- Check for working C compiler: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/cc - skipped
      -- Detecting C compile features
      -- Detecting C compile features - done
      -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
      -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
      -- Check for working CXX compiler: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/c++ - skipped
      -- Detecting CXX compile features
      -- Detecting CXX compile features - done
      -- Configuring done
      -- Generating done
      -- Build files have been written to: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-wheel-3e9istkf/cmake/_skbuild/linux-armv8l-3.8/cmake-build/LibUV-build
      [ 42%] Performing build step for 'LibUV'
      Scanning dependencies of target uv
      [  1%] Building C object CMakeFiles/uv.dir/src/fs-poll.c.o
      [  2%] Building C object CMakeFiles/uv.dir/src/inet.c.o
      [  4%] Building C object CMakeFiles/uv.dir/src/threadpool.c.o
      [  5%] Building C object CMakeFiles/uv.dir/src/timer.c.o
      [  7%] Building C object CMakeFiles/uv.dir/src/uv-common.c.o
      [  8%] Building C object CMakeFiles/uv.dir/src/uv-data-getter-setters.c.o
      [ 10%] Building C object CMakeFiles/uv.dir/src/version.c.o
      [ 11%] Building C object CMakeFiles/uv.dir/src/unix/async.c.o
      [ 13%] Building C object CMakeFiles/uv.dir/src/unix/core.c.o
      [ 14%] Building C object CMakeFiles/uv.dir/src/unix/dl.c.o
      [ 16%] Building C object CMakeFiles/uv.dir/src/unix/fs.c.o
      [ 17%] Building C object CMakeFiles/uv.dir/src/unix/getaddrinfo.c.o
      [ 19%] Building C object CMakeFiles/uv.dir/src/unix/getnameinfo.c.o
      [ 20%] Building C object CMakeFiles/uv.dir/src/unix/loop-watcher.c.o
      [ 22%] Building C object CMakeFiles/uv.dir/src/unix/loop.c.o
      [ 23%] Building C object CMakeFiles/uv.dir/src/unix/pipe.c.o
      /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-wheel-3e9istkf/cmake/_skbuild/linux-armv8l-3.8/cmake-build/LibUV-src/src/unix/pipe.c:252:15: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'socklen_t' (aka 'int') and 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned int') [-Wsign-compare]
        if (addrlen >= *size) {
            ~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~~~
      1 warning generated.
      [ 25%] Building C object CMakeFiles/uv.dir/src/unix/poll.c.o
      [ 26%] Building C object CMakeFiles/uv.dir/src/unix/process.c.o
      [ 27%] Building C object CMakeFiles/uv.dir/src/unix/signal.c.o
      [ 29%] Building C object CMakeFiles/uv.dir/src/unix/stream.c.o
      [ 30%] Building C object CMakeFiles/uv.dir/src/unix/tcp.c.o
      [ 32%] Building C object CMakeFiles/uv.dir/src/unix/thread.c.o
      [ 33%] Building C object CMakeFiles/uv.dir/src/unix/tty.c.o
      [ 35%] Building C object CMakeFiles/uv.dir/src/unix/udp.c.o
      [ 36%] Building C object CMakeFiles/uv.dir/src/unix/android-ifaddrs.c.o
      [ 38%] Building C object CMakeFiles/uv.dir/src/unix/linux-core.c.o
      [ 39%] Building C object CMakeFiles/uv.dir/src/unix/linux-inotify.c.o
      [ 41%] Building C object CMakeFiles/uv.dir/src/unix/linux-syscalls.c.o
      [ 42%] Building C object CMakeFiles/uv.dir/src/unix/procfs-exepath.c.o
      [ 44%] Building C object CMakeFiles/uv.dir/src/unix/pthread-fixes.c.o
      [ 45%] Building C object CMakeFiles/uv.dir/src/unix/sysinfo-loadavg.c.o
      [ 47%] Building C object CMakeFiles/uv.dir/src/unix/sysinfo-memory.c.o
      [ 48%] Building C object CMakeFiles/uv.dir/src/unix/proctitle.c.o
      [ 50%] Linking C shared library libuv.so
      [ 50%] Built target uv
      Scanning dependencies of target uv_a
      [ 51%] Building C object CMakeFiles/uv_a.dir/src/fs-poll.c.o
      [ 52%] Building C object CMakeFiles/uv_a.dir/src/inet.c.o
      [ 54%] Building C object CMakeFiles/uv_a.dir/src/threadpool.c.o
      [ 55%] Building C object CMakeFiles/uv_a.dir/src/timer.c.o
      [ 57%] Building C object CMakeFiles/uv_a.dir/src/uv-common.c.o
      [ 58%] Building C object CMakeFiles/uv_a.dir/src/uv-data-getter-setters.c.o
      [ 60%] Building C object CMakeFiles/uv_a.dir/src/version.c.o
      [ 61%] Building C object CMakeFiles/uv_a.dir/src/unix/async.c.o
      [ 63%] Building C object CMakeFiles/uv_a.dir/src/unix/core.c.o
      [ 64%] Building C object CMakeFiles/uv_a.dir/src/unix/dl.c.o
      [ 66%] Building C object CMakeFiles/uv_a.dir/src/unix/fs.c.o
      [ 67%] Building C object CMakeFiles/uv_a.dir/src/unix/getaddrinfo.c.o
      [ 69%] Building C object CMakeFiles/uv_a.dir/src/unix/getnameinfo.c.o
      [ 70%] Building C object CMakeFiles/uv_a.dir/src/unix/loop-watcher.c.o
      [ 72%] Building C object CMakeFiles/uv_a.dir/src/unix/loop.c.o
      [ 73%] Building C object CMakeFiles/uv_a.dir/src/unix/pipe.c.o
      /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-wheel-3e9istkf/cmake/_skbuild/linux-armv8l-3.8/cmake-build/LibUV-src/src/unix/pipe.c:252:15: warning: comparison of integers of different signs: 'socklen_t' (aka 'int') and 'size_t' (aka 'unsigned int') [-Wsign-compare]
        if (addrlen >= *size) {
            ~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~~~
      1 warning generated.
      [ 75%] Building C object CMakeFiles/uv_a.dir/src/unix/poll.c.o
      [ 76%] Building C object CMakeFiles/uv_a.dir/src/unix/process.c.o
      [ 77%] Building C object CMakeFiles/uv_a.dir/src/unix/signal.c.o
      [ 79%] Building C object CMakeFiles/uv_a.dir/src/unix/stream.c.o
      [ 80%] Building C object CMakeFiles/uv_a.dir/src/unix/tcp.c.o
      [ 82%] Building C object CMakeFiles/uv_a.dir/src/unix/thread.c.o
      [ 83%] Building C object CMakeFiles/uv_a.dir/src/unix/tty.c.o
      [ 85%] Building C object CMakeFiles/uv_a.dir/src/unix/udp.c.o
      [ 86%] Building C object CMakeFiles/uv_a.dir/src/unix/android-ifaddrs.c.o
      [ 88%] Building C object CMakeFiles/uv_a.dir/src/unix/linux-core.c.o
      [ 89%] Building C object CMakeFiles/uv_a.dir/src/unix/linux-inotify.c.o
      [ 91%] Building C object CMakeFiles/uv_a.dir/src/unix/linux-syscalls.c.o
      [ 92%] Building C object CMakeFiles/uv_a.dir/src/unix/procfs-exepath.c.o
      [ 94%] Building C object CMakeFiles/uv_a.dir/src/unix/pthread-fixes.c.o
      [ 95%] Building C object CMakeFiles/uv_a.dir/src/unix/sysinfo-loadavg.c.o
      [ 97%] Building C object CMakeFiles/uv_a.dir/src/unix/sysinfo-memory.c.o
      [ 98%] Building C object CMakeFiles/uv_a.dir/src/unix/proctitle.c.o
      [100%] Linking C static library libuv_a.a
      [100%] Built target uv_a
      [ 45%] Performing install step for 'LibUV'
      [ 50%] Built target uv
      [100%] Built target uv_a
      Install the project...
      -- Install configuration: "Release"
      -- Installing: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-wheel-3e9istkf/cmake/_skbuild/linux-armv8l-3.8/cmake-build/LibUV-install/include
      -- Installing: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-wheel-3e9istkf/cmake/_skbuild/linux-armv8l-3.8/cmake-build/LibUV-install/include/uv.h
      -- Installing: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-wheel-3e9istkf/cmake/_skbuild/linux-armv8l-3.8/cmake-build/LibUV-install/include/uv
      -- Installing: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-wheel-3e9istkf/cmake/_skbuild/linux-armv8l-3.8/cmake-build/LibUV-install/include/uv/os390.h
      -- Installing: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-wheel-3e9istkf/cmake/_skbuild/linux-armv8l-3.8/cmake-build/LibUV-install/include/uv/android-ifaddrs.h
      -- Installing: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-wheel-3e9istkf/cmake/_skbuild/linux-armv8l-3.8/cmake-build/LibUV-install/include/uv/tree.h
      -- Installing: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-wheel-3e9istkf/cmake/_skbuild/linux-armv8l-3.8/cmake-build/LibUV-install/include/uv/darwin.h
      -- Installing: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-wheel-3e9istkf/cmake/_skbuild/linux-armv8l-3.8/cmake-build/LibUV-install/include/uv/pthread-barrier.h
      -- Installing: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-wheel-3e9istkf/cmake/_skbuild/linux-armv8l-3.8/cmake-build/LibUV-install/include/uv/version.h
      -- Installing: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-wheel-3e9istkf/cmake/_skbuild/linux-armv8l-3.8/cmake-build/LibUV-install/include/uv/unix.h
      -- Installing: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-wheel-3e9istkf/cmake/_skbuild/linux-armv8l-3.8/cmake-build/LibUV-install/include/uv/errno.h
      -- Installing: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-wheel-3e9istkf/cmake/_skbuild/linux-armv8l-3.8/cmake-build/LibUV-install/include/uv/linux.h
      -- Installing: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-wheel-3e9istkf/cmake/_skbuild/linux-armv8l-3.8/cmake-build/LibUV-install/include/uv/aix.h
      -- Installing: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-wheel-3e9istkf/cmake/_skbuild/linux-armv8l-3.8/cmake-build/LibUV-install/include/uv/stdint-msvc2008.h
      -- Installing: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-wheel-3e9istkf/cmake/_skbuild/linux-armv8l-3.8/cmake-build/LibUV-install/include/uv/bsd.h
      -- Installing: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-wheel-3e9istkf/cmake/_skbuild/linux-armv8l-3.8/cmake-build/LibUV-install/include/uv/sunos.h
      -- Installing: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-wheel-3e9istkf/cmake/_skbuild/linux-armv8l-3.8/cmake-build/LibUV-install/include/uv/threadpool.h
      -- Installing: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-wheel-3e9istkf/cmake/_skbuild/linux-armv8l-3.8/cmake-build/LibUV-install/include/uv/posix.h
      -- Installing: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-wheel-3e9istkf/cmake/_skbuild/linux-armv8l-3.8/cmake-build/LibUV-install/include/uv/win.h
      -- Installing: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-wheel-3e9istkf/cmake/_skbuild/linux-armv8l-3.8/cmake-build/LibUV-install/share/doc/libuv/LICENSE
      -- Installing: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-wheel-3e9istkf/cmake/_skbuild/linux-armv8l-3.8/cmake-build/LibUV-install/lib/pkgconfig/LICENSE
      -- Installing: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-wheel-3e9istkf/cmake/_skbuild/linux-armv8l-3.8/cmake-build/LibUV-install/lib/pkgconfig/libuv.pc
      -- Installing: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-wheel-3e9istkf/cmake/_skbuild/linux-armv8l-3.8/cmake-build/LibUV-install/lib/libuv.so
      -- Installing: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-wheel-3e9istkf/cmake/_skbuild/linux-armv8l-3.8/cmake-build/LibUV-install/lib/libuv_a.a
      [ 48%] Completed 'LibUV'
      [ 48%] Built target LibUV
      Scanning dependencies of target CMakeProject-build
      [ 51%] Creating directories for 'CMakeProject-build'
      [ 54%] No download step for 'CMakeProject-build'
      [ 57%] No update step for 'CMakeProject-build'
      [ 60%] No patch step for 'CMakeProject-build'
      [ 63%] Performing configure step for 'CMakeProject-build'
      loading initial cache file /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-wheel-3e9istkf/cmake/_skbuild/linux-armv8l-3.8/cmake-build/initial-cache.txt
      loading initial cache file /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-wheel-3e9istkf/cmake/_skbuild/linux-armv8l-3.8/cmake-build/CMakeProject-build-prefix/tmp/CMakeProject-build-cache-Release.cmake
      -- The C compiler identification is Clang 10.0.1
      -- The CXX compiler identification is Clang 10.0.1
      -- Detecting C compiler ABI info
      -- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
      -- Check for working C compiler: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/cc - skipped
      -- Detecting C compile features
      -- Detecting C compile features - done
      -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
      -- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - failed
      -- Check for working CXX compiler: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/c++
      -- Check for working CXX compiler: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/c++ - broken
      CMake Error at /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/share/cmake-3.18/Modules/CMakeTestCXXCompiler.cmake:59 (message):
        The C++ compiler

          "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/c++"

        is not able to compile a simple test program.

        It fails with the following output:

          Change Dir: /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-wheel-3e9istkf/cmake/_skbuild/linux-armv8l-3.8/cmake-build/CMakeProject-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp

          Run Build Command(s):/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/make cmTC_793bc/fast && make[3]: Entering directory '/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-wheel-3e9istkf/cmake/_skbuild/linux-armv8l-3.8/cmake-build/CMakeProject-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
          /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/make  -f CMakeFiles/cmTC_793bc.dir/build.make CMakeFiles/cmTC_793bc.dir/build
          make[4]: Entering directory '/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-wheel-3e9istkf/cmake/_skbuild/linux-armv8l-3.8/cmake-build/CMakeProject-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
          Building CXX object CMakeFiles/cmTC_793bc.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o
          /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/c++   -g -o CMakeFiles/cmTC_793bc.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -c /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-wheel-3e9istkf/cmake/_skbuild/linux-armv8l-3.8/cmake-build/CMakeProject-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp/testCXXCompiler.cxx
          Linking CXX executable cmTC_793bc
          /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/cmake -E cmake_link_script CMakeFiles/cmTC_793bc.dir/link.txt --verbose=1
          /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/c++ -g -static-libstdc++ -static-libgcc -lrt  CMakeFiles/cmTC_793bc.dir/testCXXCompiler.cxx.o -o cmTC_793bc
          /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-ld: cannot find -lc++_shared
          clang-10: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
          make[4]: *** [CMakeFiles/cmTC_793bc.dir/build.make:106: cmTC_793bc] Error 1
          make[4]: Leaving directory '/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-wheel-3e9istkf/cmake/_skbuild/linux-armv8l-3.8/cmake-build/CMakeProject-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'
          make[3]: *** [Makefile:140: cmTC_793bc/fast] Error 2
          make[3]: Leaving directory '/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-wheel-3e9istkf/cmake/_skbuild/linux-armv8l-3.8/cmake-build/CMakeProject-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeTmp'





        CMake will not be able to correctly generate this project.
      Call Stack (most recent call first):
        CMakeLists.txt:7 (project)


      -- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
      See also "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-wheel-3e9istkf/cmake/_skbuild/linux-armv8l-3.8/cmake-build/CMakeProject-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
      See also "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-wheel-3e9istkf/cmake/_skbuild/linux-armv8l-3.8/cmake-build/CMakeProject-build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
      make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/CMakeProject-build.dir/build.make:131: CMakeProject-build-prefix/src/CMakeProject-build-stamp/CMakeProject-build-configure] Error 1
      make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:130: CMakeFiles/CMakeProject-build.dir/all] Error 2
      make: *** [Makefile:149: all] Error 2
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/skbuild/setuptools_wrap.py", line 589, in setup
          cmkr.make(make_args, env=env)
        File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/skbuild/cmaker.py", line 496, in make
          raise SKBuildError(

      An error occurred while building with CMake.
        Command:
          cmake --build . --target install --config Release --
        Source directory:
          /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-wheel-3e9istkf/cmake
        Working directory:
          /data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-wheel-3e9istkf/cmake/_skbuild/linux-armv8l-3.8/cmake-build
      Please see CMake's output for more information.
      ----------------------------------------
      ERROR: Failed building wheel for cmake
    ERROR: Failed to build one or more wheels
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/installer.py", line 128, in fetch_build_egg
        subprocess.check_call(cmd)
      File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
        raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
    subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/python3', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', '/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/tmp1hbw_d_z', '--quiet', 'cmake!=3.17,!=3.17.0']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

    During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/pip-install-891uqs3t/qiskit-aer/setup.py", line 56, in <module>
        setup(
      File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/skbuild/setuptools_wrap.py", line 468, in setup
        return upstream_setup(*args, **kw)
      File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 143, in setup
        _install_setup_requires(attrs)
      File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/__init__.py", line 138, in _install_setup_requires
        dist.fetch_build_eggs(dist.setup_requires)
      File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 695, in fetch_build_eggs
        resolved_dists = pkg_resources.working_set.resolve(
      File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 781, in resolve
        dist = best[req.key] = env.best_match(
      File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1066, in best_match
        return self.obtain(req, installer)
      File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 1078, in obtain
        return installer(requirement)
      File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py", line 754, in fetch_build_egg
        return fetch_build_egg(self, req)
      File "/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/lib/python3.8/site-packages/setuptools/installer.py", line 130, in fetch_build_egg
        raise DistutilsError(str(e))
    distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Command '['/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/bin/python3', '-m', 'pip', '--disable-pip-version-check', 'wheel', '--no-deps', '-w', '/data/data/com.termux/files/usr/tmp/tmp1hbw_d_z', '--quiet', 'cmake!=3.17,!=3.17.0']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

**Is there any way how to get Qiskit running on my mobile?**

Comment: Seems the `qiskit` needs `ninja` and `cmake` but cmake through the `pip` is breaking. No clear resolutions yet but discussions going on [here](https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/issues/10065) and [here](https://github.com/termux/termux-packages/issues/8951).